# How to show a product overview sorted by location in C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently stuck on a school project and would like some help on how to proceed. It's an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with C#.

I'm wondering how I can show an overview of products sorted by the factory where they are stored, which also shows how many of those products are in stock.
So for example Factory1 would have 2 apples and 1 banana, Factory2 would have 3 apples and 4 pears etc.

I know I could use ViewModels but I'm not sure how I can get the data so that the products correspond with the right factory. And if I do have that data how would I show it in a view?

My Product Model:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductCode { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int FactoryCode { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "€ {0:n}")]
    public decimal BuyingPrice { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "€ {0:n}")]
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

My Factory Model:

```
public class Factory
{
    [Key]
    public int FactoryCode { get; set; }

    public string FactoryName { get; set; }
    public string SelectFactory { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show the products without sorting?

Comment: I could use the Product View for that right? But I need to have them sorted by Factory on a new page and show what's in stock.

Comment: well I guess you are talking about summary (Report) of factories product, Isn't it? If yes, then You need to write query with `group by`clause.